# How to download image from iCloud without re-saving it?

Tags: swift, photokit, phimagemanager

I ran into a problem when trying to pick photo from gallery (app crashes when I pick image uploaded on iCloud).
So my first solution was to check if image is on device and if not, then download it from iCloud.

I used this code

```
let manager = PHImageManager.default()
let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
requestOptions.resizeMode = .exact
requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat;

// Request Image
manager.requestImageData(for: asset, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (data, str, orientation, info) -> Void in
// Do somethign with Image Data
})
```

I get imageData in this situation, but if I want to save it, it saves into **new photo**. So I get copy of image in Photos instead getting **one original imag**e that stores on device.

So my question is how to download image **without re-saving it**. 
Basically I want same behaviour as in photos app (when photo is not on device, it downloads photo and save it into same picture instead creating copy of it)

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue, here is a workaround for it:

Set [`isNetworkAccessAllowed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagerequestoptions/1616934-isnetworkaccessallowed) to `false`:

```
requestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = false
```

That's because you need to make sure that we will *not* fetch it from the iCloud. At this point, if the image is not downloaded, the `data` in `resultHandler` should be `nil`:

```
manager.requestImageData(for: PHAsset(), options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (data, str, orientation, info) -> Void in
    if let fetchedData = data {
        // the image is already downloaded
    } else {
        // the image is not downloaded...
        // now what you should do is to set isNetworkAccessAllowed to true
        // and make a new request to get it from iCloud.
    }
})
```

Furthermore, you could leverage [`PHImageResultIsInCloudKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimageresultisincloudkey):

```
manager.requestImageData(for: PHAsset(), options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (data, str, orientation, info) -> Void in
    if let keyNSNumber = info?[PHImageResultIsInCloudKey] as? NSNumber {
        if keyNSNumber.boolValue {
            // its on iCloud...
            // read the "keep in mind" below note,
            // now what you should do is to set isNetworkAccessAllowed to true
            // and make a new request.
        } else {
            //
        }
    }
})
```

As per mentioned in [`PHImageResultIsInCloudKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimageresultisincloudkey) documentation, keep in mind that:

> If true, no image was provided, because the asset data must be
>   downloaded from iCloud. To download the data, submit another request,
>   and specify true for the isNetworkAccessAllowed option.

Comment: So if I set is network access allowed then photo will be downloaded into original image without re-saving?